# Something wrong in query get wrong employee_id in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I am using CI for my project its working great. but i dont understand whats wrong in my query that i got wrong employee_id. I am writing 1 query where i got everything correct from db except my employee_id.i got some other employee_id.
i have employee_id in so many tables.

my query:

```
$this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('app_users');
  $where =  ' `USER_NAME` = "'.$username.'" '
            . 'AND SUBSTR(PASSWORD, '.($char1).', 1) = \''.$pass1.'\' '
            . 'AND SUBSTR(PASSWORD, '.($char2).', 1) = \''.$pass2.'\' ' 
            . 'AND SUBSTR(PASSWORD, '.($char3).', 1) = \''.$pass3.'\' '
            . 'AND SUBSTR(PIN, '.($char11).', 1) = \''.$pass4.'\' '
            . 'AND SUBSTR(PIN, '.($char22).', 1) = \''.$pass5.'\' '
            . 'AND SUBSTR(PIN, '.($char33).', 1) = \''.$pass6.'\' ';     
  $this->db->where($where);

     $this->db->join('employee_details', 'app_users.EMPLOYEE_ID = employee_details.EMPLOYEE_ID', 'LEFT');
     $this->db->join('employee_master', 'app_users.EMPLOYEE_ID = employee_master.EMPLOYEE_ID', 'LEFT');
     $this->db->join('designation_master', 'employee_details.DESIGNATION_ID = designation_master.DESIGNATION_ID', 'LEFT');
     $this->db->join('employee_visa_details', 'employee_details.EMPLOYEE_ID = employee_visa_details.EMPLOYEE_ID', 'LEFT');
     $this->db->join('visa_status_master', 'employee_visa_details.VISA_STATUS_ID = visa_status_master.VISA_STATUS_ID', 'LEFT');
     $this->db->join('employment_status_master', 'employee_details.EMPLOYMENT_STATUS_ID = employment_status_master.EMPLOYMENT_STATUS_ID', 'LEFT');             
     $this->db->join('employee_skills', 'employee_details.EMPLOYEE_ID = employee_skills.EMPLOYEE_SKILLS_ID', 'LEFT'); 

     $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();
```

Some times i get error in query.

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' 1) = '' AND SUBSTR(PASSWORD, , 1) = '' AND SUBSTR(PASSWORD, , 1) = '' AND SUBST' at line 10

SELECT * FROM `app_users` LEFT JOIN `employee_details` ON `app_users`.`EMPLOYEE_ID` = `employee_details`.`EMPLOYEE_ID` LEFT JOIN `employee_master` ON `app_users`.`EMPLOYEE_ID` = `employee_master`.`EMPLOYEE_ID` LEFT JOIN `designation_master` ON `employee_details`.`DESIGNATION_ID` = `designation_master`.`DESIGNATION_ID` LEFT JOIN `employee_visa_details` ON `employee_details`.`EMPLOYEE_ID` = `employee_visa_details`.`EMPLOYEE_ID` LEFT JOIN `visa_status_master` ON `employee_visa_details`.`VISA_STATUS_ID` = `visa_status_master`.`VISA_STATUS_ID` LEFT JOIN `employment_status_master` ON `employee_details`.`EMPLOYMENT_STATUS_ID` = `employment_status_master`.`EMPLOYMENT_STATUS_ID` LEFT JOIN `employee_skills` ON `employee_details`.`EMPLOYEE_ID` = `employee_skills`.`EMPLOYEE_SKILLS_ID` WHERE `USER_NAME` = "" AND SUBSTR(PASSWORD, , 1) = '' AND SUBSTR(PASSWORD, , 1) = '' AND SUBSTR(PASSWORD, , 1) = '' AND SUBSTR(PIN, , 1) = '' AND SUBSTR(PIN, , 1) = '' AND SUBSTR(PIN, , 1) = ''

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/CodeIgniter-3.1.6/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
```

I am not undestanding whats wrong with my query. because i am getting all other data correct but different `employee_id`.

this is my controller for the same:

```
  $this->load->model('user_model');
        $username = $this->input->post('user_email');
        $pass1 = $this->input->post('pass1');
        $pass2 = $this->input->post('pass2');
        $pass3 = $this->input->post('pass3');

        $char1 = $this->input->post('char1');
        $char2 = $this->input->post('char2');
        $char3 = $this->input->post('char3');


        $pass4 = $this->input->post('pass4');
        $pass5 = $this->input->post('pass5');
        $pass6 = $this->input->post('pass6');

        $char11 = $this->input->post('char11');
        $char22 = $this->input->post('char22');
        $char33 = $this->input->post('char33');
        /*$password = $this->input->post('user_password');
        $pin = $this->input->post('user_pin');*/
        $is_valid = $this->user_model->validate($username,$char1,$pass1, $char2,$pass2, $char3,$pass3,$char11,$pass4,$char22, $pass5, $char33,$pass6);
```

please help me for the same.thanks in advance.

Comment: Your problem is probably caused by calling the `validate()` method with invalid (empty) parameters (`$pass1` to `$pass6` etc.) - find out why the parameters are empty.

Comment: Why are you adding all business logic to the query? Instead, you can pass only the structured data that is required in the query. Actually, you are giving addition task to the query. Model is only meant for querying to the database. If you provide the data in the form array and run the query it is also easy to trace.

Comment: actually my query shows employee_id but in controller `$is_valid` shows null in it

Comment: my query was wrong. i got solution thanks for your reply guys